# PHP array question

Tags: php, html

Is it alright if I put the `cat[]` array value in the `for`, `name` and `id` attributes.

code.

```
<label for="cat[]">' . $cat['category'] . '</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" id="cat[]" value="' . $cat['id'] . '" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:** No.

### Long Answer

No because:

- Square brackets are invalid characters for both the for and id attributes.
- Using square brackets in the name attribute signals to php to create an array. This implies you have multiple form elements with the name `cat[]`. However, the id attribute must be unique. Therefore, you can't have the id and name equal. If you don't have a decent unique id for each checkbox then just increment cat. So the first checkbox would have an id of `cat1`, the second an id of `cat2` and so on.
- If you created multiple checkboxes with the same id attribute, your label elements would not know which inputs to point to as the for attribute cannot uniquely identify an input. This would create unpredictable behaviour and make it pointless to have a for attribute in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

No, just name (passed to server side), ID must be unique with no special characters and cannot start with a number.

Answer (score 0):

From w3C

character "[" is not allowed in the value of attribute "for"

character "[" is not allowed in the value of attribute "id"

Try it out
[validator](http://validator.w3.org/)